# GCP CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME ignore account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk

I'm trying to set up multiple configuration in GCP like the following

```
NAME        IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT              PROJECT   COMPUTE_DEFAULT_ZONE  COMPUTE_DEFAULT_REGION
default     False      mail_a@mail.com       prj_a
test        True       mail_b@mail.com       prj_b
```

When I execute commands from the CLI all works correctly, but if I make a test from Python seem to read wrong account

```
import os
os.environ['CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME'] = 'test'
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()
```

I get following error, like the client is trying to access corretly in test configuration but with default account mail_a@mail.com instead of mail_b@mail.com

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=prj_b&projection=noAcl: mail_a@mail.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.
```

I also tried to force account with

```
os.environ['CLOUDSDK_CORE_ACCOUNT'] = 'mail_b@mail.com'
```

but seems to be ignored

Any idea?

UPDATE

The problem seems to be related with application-default not supporting multiple configuration. You need to run each time `gcloud auth application-default login` for each account.

Comment: Do not manually change the Google Cloud SDK CLI (gcloud) environment. Use supported commands. There are a number of things that happen in the background with your credentials. If you really need to do this, study the source code first which is public.

Comment: I don't understand. i'm trying to specify which named configuration to be used by my python script locally

Comment: Use the gcloud commands. Read the documentation for setting the configuration.

Comment: Has the gcloud documentation says here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations and here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations the environment variables are also a way to set configurations

Answer (score 0):

Paolo,

In regard to the error:

“google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403”

“mail_a@mail.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.”

The issue is related to IAM permissions, it seems like the account ‘mail_a@mail.com’ doesn’t have the right role in the Project ‘prj_b’.

So, please make sure that the above account has the predefined role [link1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)  ‘Storage Admin’ which contains all the ‘storage.buckets.*’ permissions, or any of the Primitive roles [link2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#primitive-roles) : Viewer, Editor and Owner; in the project ‘prj_b’.

Once you have the IAM roles under control, you have to automate the authentication within your python code to avoid manual authentication tasks.

I noticed you’re using the ‘os.environ’ in your code, which is a ‘environment variable’ and it works when you run all from the CLI but for some reason is not working well.

Since you’re using the ‘Cloud Storage Client Libraries’ and python code, I suggest you to take a look at this public documentation [link3](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) , the authentication methods are described in this guide [link4](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) :

1.- Finding credentials automatically
2.- Passing credentials manually

You’ll find python code examples in there.

Here’s the Storage Client documentation [link5](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html)

I hope you find the above information

Comment: Ok, but what i was trying to accomplish was using the application default credential to authenticate my python script locally instead of generating a new service account. it works fine only with one configuration, i hoped application default credential stores multiple credentials since - -configuration flag is supported, but from glocloud folder i always see only one service account in the root instead being associated with the named configuration. Often i work in projects where i don't have permission to generate service account so using my credential would be easy.